# Javascript output in alert is different in console, and counter is not working properly even when condition is met

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm making a rock paper scissors games where the counter should add 1 if user wins, add 0.5 if it's a tie, and remains the same if user lost. But in the alert and what's shown in the console doesn't match. Sometimes its shown in the alert that I win and in the console its shown I lose or its a tie. And the counter doesn't add up correctly.
[image: Image here]

In the image above it's shown 3 wins, 1 tie, and 1 lose. It should show I've won 3.5 games but it shows 5.5. And there is only 5 games played so it should be impossible to win 5.5.

Here is the code:

```
let winCounter = 0;

// playRound function will play a game of rock, paper, scissors and returns the result
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let getPlayerInsensitive = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

  if (getPlayerInsensitive === "rock" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    winCounter+=0.5;
    return "It's a tie, both are Rock";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    winCounter = winCounter;
    return "You Lose! Paper beats Rock";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    winCounter+=1;
    return "You win! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    winCounter+=1;
    return "You win! Paper beats Rock";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "paper" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    winCounter+=0.5;
    return "It's a tie! Both are Paper";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    winCounter = winCounter;
    return "You lose! Scissors beats Paper";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    winCounter = winCounter;
    return "You lose! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    winCounter=0.5;
    return "It's a tie! Both are Scissors";
  } else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    winCounter+=1;
    return "You win! Scissors beat Paper";
  } else {
    return "Check your spelling!";
  }

}

// game function returns the winner after five rounds
function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    let getSelect = prompt("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors", "");
    if (getSelect === null || getSelect === "") {
      alert("You clicked Cancel!");
    }
    alert(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
    if (i < 5) {
      console.log(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
    }

    //outputs the winner of 5 games

    if (i === 4) {
      alert("You've played 5 games");
      if (winCounter >= 3) {
       alert(`You've won ${winCounter} out of 5 games. You win!`);
       return `You've won ${winCounter} out of 5 games. You win!`;
    } else if (winCounter === 2.5) {
       alert(`You've won 2.5 out of 5 games. It's a tie!`);
       return `You've won 2.5 out of 5 games. It's a tie!`;
    } else if (winCounter < 2.5) {
       alert(`You've won ${winCounter} out of 5 games. You lost!`);
       return `You've won ${winCounter} out of 5 games. You lost!`;
    }

   }
 }

}

console.log(game());
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JaredDev/o62hr7as/125/

Comment: Don't use `alert`, it can _only_ show strings, and if you're trying to make it show "not a string", it will find whatever conversion method it can in however many steps necessary to turn that thing into a string anyway. Just use the console for everything, and if you need to present your users with dismissible information, the HTML spec literally has an element for that: [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) (yes, it'll need a sprinkle of extra JS, but it's worth it)

Comment: You've got a `winCounter=0.5` where it should be `winCounter += 0.5` (Scissors vs Scissors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does it show different results in alert and console.log**

It's because you called the `computerPlay` function twice, thus could returns different selection each time it is called,

```
alert(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
if (i < 5) {
  console.log(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
}
```

you could change it to this, so it is called only once

```
const result = playRound(getSelect, computerPlay())
alert(result);
if (i < 5) {
  console.log(result)
}
```

also why the score could be more than it should have, its because `playRound` function also called twice each turn

Answer (score 1):

#### Caling code with random behaviour and side-effects twice

This piece of code produces an unintended result because the function `computerPlay` has *random behaviour* and the function `playRound` has has *side-effects* (modifies the `winCounter`).

```js
alert(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
if (i < 5) {
  console.log(playRound(getSelect, computerPlay()));
}
```

You could correct this part of the problem by calling the function only once and assigning its result to a variable:

```
const result = playRound(getSelect, computerPlay());
alert(result);
if (i < 5) {
  console.log(result);
}
```

#### Typo

You also have a typo:

```js
} else if (getPlayerInsensitive === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
  winCounter=0.5;
  return "It's a tie! Both are Scissors";
```

This should say `+=` not just `=`:

```
  winCounter+=0.5;
```